# Why does my query return the wrong schema name for triggers?

Tags: sql-server

I retrieve triggers on a SQL Server 2008 express by this simple query:

```
SELECT
    [so].[name] AS [trigger_name],
    USER_NAME([so].[uid]) AS [trigger_owner],
    USER_NAME([so2].[uid]) AS [table_schema],
    OBJECT_NAME([so].[parent_obj]) AS [table_name],
    OBJECTPROPERTY( [so].[id], 'ExecIsUpdateTrigger') AS [isupdate],
    OBJECTPROPERTY( [so].[id], 'ExecIsDeleteTrigger') AS [isdelete],
    OBJECTPROPERTY( [so].[id], 'ExecIsInsertTrigger') AS [isinsert],
    OBJECTPROPERTY( [so].[id], 'ExecIsAfterTrigger') AS [isafter],
    OBJECTPROPERTY( [so].[id], 'ExecIsInsteadOfTrigger') AS [isinsteadof],
    OBJECTPROPERTY([so].[id], 'ExecIsTriggerDisabled') AS [disabled] 
FROM sysobjects AS [so]
INNER JOIN sysobjects AS so2 ON so.parent_obj = so2.Id
WHERE [so].[type] = 'TR'
```

everthing seems to work, but the table_schema is WRONG.
it always returns `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` while it should return `SalesLT`

The database I tested this on is the sample db from microsoft: AdventureWorks.

Why is this and how can I get the correct table_schema for my triggers ?

Maybe there is a better way to get the triggers from sql server ? (must work on as many SQL Server versions as possible)

Comment: Have you considered that it's returning the correct value, and your assumption about what the value should be is incorrect? I'm not saying that's the case (I don't know), but if the SQL is correct and it's returning a value, then it seems like it believes that's the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sysobjects catalog view is deprecated.  Use sys.objects intead.  Note that owners and schemas are different things.  See below example.

```
SELECT
    [so].[name] AS [trigger_name],
    USER_NAME(OBJECTPROPERTY([so].[object_id], 'OwnerId')) AS [trigger_owner],
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([so2].[object_id]) AS [table_schema],
    OBJECT_NAME([so].[parent_object_id]) AS [table_name],
    OBJECTPROPERTY( [so].[object_id], 'ExecIsUpdateTrigger') AS [isupdate],
    OBJECTPROPERTY( [so].[object_id], 'ExecIsDeleteTrigger') AS [isdelete],
    OBJECTPROPERTY( [so].[object_id], 'ExecIsInsertTrigger') AS [isinsert],
    OBJECTPROPERTY( [so].[object_id], 'ExecIsAfterTrigger') AS [isafter],
    OBJECTPROPERTY( [so].[object_id], 'ExecIsInsteadOfTrigger') AS [isinsteadof],
    OBJECTPROPERTY([so].[object_id], 'ExecIsTriggerDisabled') AS [disabled] 
FROM sys.objects AS [so]
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS so2 ON so.parent_object_id = so2.object_id
WHERE [so].[type] = 'TR';
```

Comment: Do I have to mark this question as answered somehow ? if so, how do I do that ?

Comment: @user3611669, did the answer helped you? If yes, then you have to by clicking the check button under votting button.

Comment: This may sound very stupid, but where is the voting button ? I cannot found it anywhere.